# ORA-00937: it is not a group function on only one grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, rdbms

I have to retrieve some data (Oracle RDBMS). I have to filter them, to grup them. So i thought about doing three nested query.
Starting from the outside in: a query to restrict a query to sort them and a query for selection (which also filter and groups them).
This is the query:

```
    @SqlQuery("select count(*) personCount, SURNAME surname, SKILL skill, ROWNUM " +
        "     from (select * " +
        "        from (select count(*) personCount, SURNAME surname, SKILL skill from people " +
        "           where ....my filters....
        "          group by SURNAME, SKILL ) " +
        "       order by personCount DESC )  " +
        "     where ROWNUM \\<= :limit ")
```

But it gives me this error: `ORA-00937: it is not a group function on only one grouping`

Why?

Comment: It seems that you are extracting SKILL without using it in GROUP BY clause

Comment: No sorry i wrote wrong, i'm using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify all the columns you select in the `group by` clause :

```
    @SqlQuery("select personCount, SURNAME surname, SKILL skill, ROWNUM " +
        "     from (select * " +
        "        from (select count(*) personCount, SURNAME surname, SKILL skill from people " +
        "           where ....my filters.... " +
        "          group by SURNAME, SKILL ) " +
        "       order by personCount DESC )  " +
        "     where ROWNUM \\<= :limit ")
```

Also, you already calculated the count of personCount, you don't need to count it again.

Note that I replaced the knowledge column with the skill column in the group by, I assumed it was a typo.

Comment: Yes now it works. I was wrong to write in the code of my question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You must not do the count in the external select:

```
   @SqlQuery("select personCount, surname, skill, ROWNUM " +
        "     from (select * " +
        "        from (select count(*) personCount, SURNAME surname, SKILL skill from people " +
        "           where ....my filters.... "
        "          group by SURNAME, SKILL) " +
        "       order by personCount DESC )  " +
        "     where ROWNUM \\<= :limit ")
```